# How to properly write a txt to use as table in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, table

I just wrote a txt. to use it as a table in ArcGIS, but for some reason when I open it, 
ArcGIS shows it in a completely wrong way. What am I doing wrong? Here is the original content:

```
Coordinate,IDW_1000,IDW_3000,IDW_5000,IDW_7000,IDW_9000,STD,Range
1950_3050,60,67.640083,67.463203,67.734276,67.493469,0.110124,0.271072
2050_250,0,63.021103,64.201378,65.227089,65.283630,0.922124,2.262527
4050_4050,80.470039,76.848450,76.499733,76.234200,76.234200,0.252144,0.614250
6050_1450,54.288288,57.713890,58.563168,58.870098,58.872475,0.473702,1.158585
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to describe both what you were expecting and the "completely wrong way"?  Embedding a screen shot would be useful.

Comment: It looks correct to me, I am wondering if it has something to do with the underscores in the "Coordinate" column data but that's just a guess.

Comment: Honestly, the text format looks just fine.  It mimics a csv file which ArcMap generally handles well.  One option may be to place your text file in Excel and save it out as a csv. @Chris R - you may have a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in the middle of writing a long answer about [making a .csvt file](http://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/) etc....but I think the problem is the first two values in "IDW_1000" are whole numbers and the last two are decimals if you change the first two values to "60.0" and "0.0" the problem is fixed(maybe ArcGIS uses the first value to decide what type of data is in the field). As a side note I split the "Coordinates" into two columns "Coord_X" and "Coord_Y" and replaced the underscore with a comma like this:

```
Coord_X,Coord_Y,IDW_1000,IDW_3000,IDW_5000,IDW_7000,IDW_9000,STD,Range
1950,3050,60.0,67.640083,67.463203,67.734276,67.493469,0.110124,0.271072
2050,250,0.0,63.021103,64.201378,65.227089,65.28363,0.922124,2.262527
4050,4050,80.470039,76.84845,76.499733,76.2342,76.2342,0.252144,0.61425
6050,1450,54.288288,57.71389,58.563168,58.870098,58.872475,0.473702,1.158585
```

Once that is done the table is displayed correctly in ArcMap:
[image]